# Can someone give me a link where i can find DevPackages for Xerces to use it with Dev-C++

Tags: xerces, dev-c++

Can someone give me a link where i can find DevPackages for Xerces to use it with Dev-C++
I am using Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2 version and want to use Xerces 3.1.1

Answer (score 0):

For Dec-C++ you'll probably need libraries compiled with MinGW because it's the underlying compiler. Xerces only distributes VC++ builds so I guess you'll have to build Xerces as described here:

http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/build-3.html#UNIX

Answer (score 0):

You can try this link :
[xerces-c_2_5_0](http://old.devpaks.org/show.php?devpak=41)